# Function SUM not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
Table devolucion

detalle_ticket_ticket_id         fecha
    20                        2013-06-04
    21                        2013-06-04
    23                        2013-06-04
    23                        2013-06-04
    23                        2013-06-04
    24                        2013-06-04
    24                        2013-06-04
    24                        2013-06-04

Table detalle_ticket

ticket_id     precio    iva   cantidad
   20          7.25      0       7.25
   21          20        0      20   
   23          12        0      12
   23          13        0      13
   23          14        0      14
   24          48.40     16     48.40
   24          18.50     16     18.50
   24          4.70      0       4.70
```

What I'm trying to do is to sum the values from the columns precio, iva, cantidad where the value from the column ticket_id is the same, I will explain better:

The first row in the column ticket_id is 20, the second is 21, the third is 23, the fourth is 23 so the third and fourth row have the same value (23) then what I need is to sum the respective values from the columns precio(values 12+13 = 25), iva (0+0=0), cantidad(12+13=25) and so on with the whole rows, the problem comes with my query which is not working as I expected. It keeps confusing me.

What I have tried so far

```
SELECT dt.ticket_id, SUM(dt.precio), SUM(iva), SUM(cantidad) 
FROM devolucion d INNER JOIN detalle_ticket dt 
ON d.detalle_ticket_ticket_id = dt.ticket_id 
WHERE DATE(d.fecha) = '2013-06-04'
GROUP BY dt.ticket_id;
```

What my (bad) query throws:

```
ticket_id     precio    iva   cantidad
   20          7.25      0       7.25
   21          20        0      20   
   23          117       0      12
   24          214.80   16      48.40
```

What I expected:

```
ticket_id     precio    iva   cantidad
   20          7.25      0       7.25
   21          20        0      20   
   23          39        0      39
   24          71.6     32      71.6
```

I have made it in sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64367

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read this http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html to understand why your usage of `GROUP BY` is wrong and will produce wrong results (and this as well: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/)

Comment: @Blackmore . . . By the way, a well articulated question, with sample data and expected results.

Comment: where's this `total` field in the select's field list coming from? it's not listed in either sample table.

Comment: @MarcB My bad, it should be cantidad not total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `sum` for each column in the `detalle_ticket` table, then you will join that subquery back to your `devolucion` table. Since you have multiple rows in each table and you are only joining on the `ticket_id` you can use the following:

```
SELECT distinct d.detalle_ticket_ticket_id, 
  dt.precio, 
  dt.iva, 
  dt.cantidad
FROM devolucion d 
INNER JOIN
(
  select ticket_id, 
    sum(precio) precio, 
    sum(iva) iva,
    sum(cantidad) cantidad
  from detalle_ticket
  group by ticket_id
) dt 
  ON d.detalle_ticket_ticket_id = dt.ticket_id 
WHERE DATE(d.fecha) = '2013-06-04';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/234c8/25). This gives a result:

```
| DETALLE_TICKET_TICKET_ID | PRECIO | IVA | cantidad |
-----------------------------------------------------
|                       20 |   7.25 |   0 |  7.25    |
|                       21 |     20 |   0 |    20    |
|                       23 |     39 |   0 |    39    |
|                       24 |   71.6 |  32 |  71.6    |
```

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you did, it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @Blackmore The key was to aggregate the data in the subquery before you join it to `devolucion`. Since you have multiple rows in each table if you apply the aggregation without a subquery the result will be multiplied by how many rows are returned for each ticket_id.  For ticket 20 you will return one row but for 23/24 you will return 9 rows but aggregation in a subquery means the `sum` will be for the 3 rows instead of 9.

Comment: I understood now, The join multiplies 3 times each ticket_id so I got 3 twleve, 3 thirteen and 3 fourteen (for the ticket_id 23) so it adds all 9 numbers and I get a spaghetti, so with the subquery only throws 3 rows not 9.  Many thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have multiple rows for a given date in both tables.  There are 3 dates for id 24 in the first table and 3 rows in the second table.  The resulting join has 9 rows, one for every combination of the two.

To fix this, do the aggregation *before* the join:

```
SELECT dt.ticket_id, SUM(dt.precio), iva, total 
FROM devolucion d INNER JOIN
     (select dt_ticket_id, sum(dt.precio) as precio, sum(dt.iva) as iva, sum(total) as total
      from detalle_ticket dt 
      group by dt_ticket_id
     ) dt
     ON d.detalle_ticket_ticket_id = dt.ticket_id 
WHERE DATE(d.fecha) = '2013-06-04'
```

I also added aggregations for `iva` and `total`.  They seemed to be missing.